# Best way to store data (in-memory) that will be filtered?

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, filtering

I need to store a collection of items (C# type in-memory) that has a number of fields such as: language, owner, key, etc. I want to store these in a way that allows for fast filtering. E.g. I might want all entries that has *language = "en"* AND *key = "key1"*. It won't be filtered often and its size may be around 10k entries, would a simple list/dictionary suffice? I'm curious about how to solve this though for bigger lists that will be filtered more often.

Comment: Either reimplement [indexing](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-index-basics/) in C# or just use DB

Comment: DB isn't an option (edited my question).

Comment: You can use in-memory [SQLite](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitecsharp/intro/) DB.

Comment: @Martheen Since when is SQLite in memory? Last time I checked it used a file.

Comment: At least [since 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845288/sqlite-memory-mode-support-persistence-to-local) Edit : Been there since [2003](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html)

Comment: I'm developing for unity which uses mono 2.x which makes third-party integration a bit of a pain... so I'm looking for a simple solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's sufficient to store it in-memory and there aren't that many variants of filtering, you could create a dictionary based data-structure.

Another solution without using a classic relational DB, is, using Lucene.net, which is a very fast search engine library. Though it has a steep learning curve and a documentation that has room for improvement ;-)
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net/

Or - just use a classic DB and take care of setting indexes correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It's sufficient to store in-memory and there aren't that many variants (it's going to be like the example I gave in my post).